# Common solution for Facebook, Twitter and Google authorization in Android

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, oauth-2.0

I want to implement authentication of following sites in my Android application.

- Facebook
- Twitter
- Goggle

So far, I went through many solutions but

- For Facebook, I need Facebook Android SDK
- For Twitter, I need twitter4j
- For Google, I have found some [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) code

So if I want all these three authentications in one Android applications, the application eventually is bulked up by the code so is there any common solution to implement all these authentication in one Android application, some light-weight solution?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this : http://kurogo.org/technology/

They have a module named Login. AFAIK, this module has support for SSO (Single Sign On). So, they should have login modules for SSO supported platforms. Google/Facebook and twitter does that. But so far they have not released any Android port of the same. But, as you might see, it is based on the popular MIT-Mobile middleware. Here is their [github repo](https://github.com/MIT-Mobile/MIT-Mobile-for-Android)

Not sure this is exactly what you are looking for or something like that does exists. But its worth giving a shot.